# How to get the order item id in Magento 2 (not the order ID)?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I need the ORDER ITEM ID in order to consume the service RefundInvoice at Magento   2 to create a credit memo with a refund (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mrg/ce/Sales/services.html).

Order item ID is I definitely something else than the order ID, since I tried that one.

So anyone an idea how I can retrieve the order item id?

Comment: The item_id may not be what you are expecting. Its auto-incrementing and doesn't review to the actual item but the record. It is mis-named, because it is actually the 'entity_id'. It remains NULL until it is written to the table, when it gains its row identity.

Answer (score 0):

//Try with below code.

```
$orderId = 1234; //put your order id.
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($orderItems as $item)
{
  echo "Order Item ID :".$item->getItemId(); //
}
```

Comment: Order Item ID :. (NULL)

Answer (score 0):

The item_id is actually the `entity_id` for sales_order_item. It is NULL until the record is saved to the database, upon when it is populated with the row ID. In order to access it and find its value, the salesOrderItem object must call ->save() first.  If you are looking for the actual "item id" (the product), use product_id. If you need to record the record ID, then call `$object->save()`, and then you can read `$object->getItemId()`